# PowerBI / DAX - Row wise division by measure

Tags: dax, powerbi

I am a heavy user of R who is trying to port some basic calculations to Power BI but unable to get DAX to perform vector/rowwise division.

For example, with this dataset:

```
Category    Value
--------    -----
A           1
A           2
B           3
C           4
```

I have created a measure: `Value Sum = SUM(Table[Value])`
and I would like to create a third column: `Value Share = Value / Value Sum` to get:

```
Category    Value    Value Share
--------    -----    -----------
A           1        0.1 
A           2        0.2
B           3        0.3
C           4        0.4
```

The equivalent in R would be :

```r
table$Value.Share = table$value/Value.Sum
```

I have tried: `Value Share = [Value] / [Value Sum]` but I ended up with 1s in all Value Share rows. Tried `SUMX` and `CALCULATETABLE` functions but I believe I am missing something fundamental. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! If you're starting out with DAX, I can highly recommend to view one of the video lectures of Alberto Cairo / Marco Russo like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klQAZLr5vxA, because your question (and all of DAX difficulty) is primarily about *contexts*.

As for your question, I think you're looking for

`=[Value]/CALCULATE(SUM([Value]); ALL(TableName))`

Of course, you can replace `SUM([Value])` with a measure name too.

See also http://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and helpful link!

Answer (score 1):

try this formula: divide([value],sum([value]))

[SNAP of DAX formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBgeN.jpg)